# Flutter FutureBuilder and navigation to a different route using Navigator.pushNamed

Tags: flutter

What I'm trying to do is to show a widget with loading status while I'm fetching some info from the web using the http client. Then based on the result to automatically navigate to a different route.

Here is my code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: FutureBuilder(
      future: http.get("https://exmaple.com"),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('ConnectionState.none.');
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Awaiting result...');
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
//              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route2');
              return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data.statusCode}');
            }
        }
        return null; // unreachable
      },
    )));
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I add `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route2');` it will throw an error.

I  understand why it is throwing the error. What I don't know is how to achieve this. All examples that I found showed that navigation happens after some user iteration `onPressed` .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple hack to make the code work.

```
// else
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0))
      .then((value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route2'));
return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data.statusCode}');
// end else
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your widget stateful and use *initState* function to make request to server:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    http.get("https://exmaple.com").then((v) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/route2'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stepped on the same problem today, found a possibly cleaner way to deal with it.

You cannot use the navigator in the `builder` method of `FutureBuilder`, but you CAN append a `.then` statement (or similar, such as `.catchError`) after the future:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) => FutureBuilder(
        future: http.get("https://exmaple.com").then((_) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route2');
        }),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
          // Build widgets
        },
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 0)).then((value) {
    MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute = MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
        providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DrawerMenuController())],
        child: PainelScreen(funcionario: keyPair!.value),
      ),
    );

    Future future = Navigator.push(context, materialPageRoute);
    future.then((value) {});
  },
);
```